# Time Picker for Qty Hour Segments in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, timepicker

I need to create an control in asp.net mvc that allows the user to select a time that is anywhere between 7am and 7pm with quarter hour segments. i.e. The user could select:

7:00am
7:15am
7:30am
7:45am
8:00am
8:15am
....
....
7:00pm

Currently ive got a dropdown that comprises of a select list with entries for every single time slot. Just wondering if anyone knows a cleaner and or better UI experience for the user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ if you want a combo date/time picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you looking into a JQuery addon: [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).
It is easy to set up, simple in use, and it looks great.

For easy access put this code into your Layout view in the  section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
        $('.timepicker').live('mousedown', function () {
            $(this).timepicker({
                stepMinute: 15,
                hourMin: 7,
                hourMax: 19
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your view have something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Time, new { @class = @"timepicker" })
```

Another JQuery option is [Timepickr](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/). I don't like it as much as the first one, but it still is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

The [Telerik DateTime Picker](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/datetimepickers.aspx) can handle this.  It defaults to an interval every half-hour, but you can [configure it to display any interval you want](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-timepicker-configuration.html#Interval), such as your 15 minutes.  It integrates with their date picker, in case you want a combined datetime picker.

It is a drop-down list, like yours, but they tend to have a lot of whiz-bang chrome on their stuff, so you might be able to configure it in other display formats.

I believe the Telerik MVC controls are free to download and use, but you have to pay if you want support.